# ForEach inside NavigationLink with @Environment(\.dismiss) makes the nav link unclickable/unresponsive

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Edit: This seems to be happening to me on Preview and on Simulator, but not on my iPhone. Since Preview (Canvas) uses simulator on the background, might be an issue with my setup here. Gonna have to reinstall and see.

--

I came across this issue while writing an app, so I isolated the problem to the simplest form I could think of below.

The main issue seems to be that if I have a ForEach inside a NavigationLink inside a child view struct where I have defined `@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss`, then I am unable to click the NavigationLink to move to the new View in Canvas and on Simulator.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationStack {
                ChildView()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    //Commenting the @Environment(\.dismiss) line below seems fix it
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink("Commend and uncomment @Environment") {
                ForEach(1...5, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("demo \(index)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Does this look like a bug?

Swift language version: 5 
iOS target version: 17.4 
Xcode version: 15.3 (15E204a)

Comment: I cannot reproduce on iOS 17.0 and Xcode 15.0.

Comment: Can't reproduce it on iOS 17.4 and XCode 15.3 either, on previews and simulator.

Comment: I tried re-installing simulators with this: 

`sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService` and `sudo rm -rf ~/Library/*/CoreSimulator`

Didn't fix it

Comment: Usually `ForEach` is inside a `List` or a `HStack`

Comment: @malhal as far as I know ForEach can be inside almost any view